# What is the difference of /etc/fstab and /etc/mtab

Tags: linux, filesystems, fstab

To auto-mount, admin can edit /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab. What is the difference of the two? If I set the same `mount` item in both, which one take effect?

In /etc/stab

`share /media/sf_share1 vboxsf gid=999,rw 0 0`

In /etc/mtab

`share /media/sf_share vboxsf gid=999,rw 0 0`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/fstab` is the one applied on boot.

`/etc/mtab`, on the other hand, shows what is currently mounted.